# Run cron job hourly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I use let's encrypt for getting certificates and I want to setup renewal for certificates.

So, I decided to check if cron works fine.

I created three file in `daily.hourly` folder:

1. test-h:

   /sbin/ifconfig >/home/bitnami/ipt
2. test-h2:

   #!/bin/bash
       /sbin/ifconfig > /home/bitnami/ipt2
3. test-h3.sh:

   #!/bin/bash
   /sbin/ifconfig >/home/bitnami/ipt3

But, I don't see my files in home directory. How to properly use cron.daily?

PS. The cron servive is started, I checked.
I restarted it also just to make sure that changes is applied.
The `crontab` file contains record for `cron.hourly`:

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

I am not linux guy, so, if it possible get me detailed answer please.

Comment: `crontab -e` try that

Comment: As I understand `crontab -e` is not recomended way, because could be deleted  by system.

Comment: Every user can have their own cron jobs I don't know  what you mean by "system"

Comment: @nogad I am not linux guy, but when I read about cron I've found that cron jobs created for user could be deleted by system on system updating for example.

Comment: Well if you are root you can do anything I don't see how that's an issue  here

Comment: Did you `chmod +x test-h test-h2 test-h3.sh`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Just found info about it, will try

Comment: @JohnZwinck. Yes, chmod helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you didn't `chmod +x` your scripts.  That's needed to make them executable.